# Retrieval of single entry by np.datetime index value failing, but not failing by range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe, whose index is based on the numpy datetime type.

I can easily access a range of dataframe entries:

```
for t in df.index.values:
    print(df[:t])
```

However have problems (KeyError) whenever I try to access a specific value.

```
for t in df.index.values:
    print(df[t])
```

End up with a workaround using .iloc, but it is messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for t in df.index:
    print(df.loc[t])
```

Comment: Not quite happy with loc. It returns a weird structure, where for single index column names becomes indices.

Comment: That's because it returns a series, which is another data type. This is really the way you should be working though, if you want to access single rows.

Answer (score 0):

`df[t]` is for column indexing, since you are iterating on your row index, use `loc` or 'iloc`.

```
for t in df.index.values:
    print(df.loc[:t])

for i, t in enumerate(df.index.values):
    print(df.iloc[:i])
```

Since you mentioned that your index is based on numpy DateTime. Pandas also accept slicing using datetime as follows:

```
df.loc[: '2018-01-01'] #All entries up to date 1st of Jan 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a universal simple solution I was looking for.

For single row index.

```
df[t:t]
```

For multi-row index.

```
df[:t]
```

Returns a nice df even for single index (with no weird *.loc style transformations where the column headers and index flip).